# using a struct that is defined in another header

Tags: c++, header

I have 2 header files. My code is similar to the following:

file1.h

```
#include "file2.h"

struct foo{
   int one;
};

//compiles if I add the following line.
//struct bar;

void dosomething(bar* param);
foo* dosomething1();
```

file2.h

```
#include "file1.h"

struct bar{
   int two;
   struct foo* two;
};

//also error in compilation time unless I add the following
//struct foo;
void dostuff(foo* param);
```

Why is it yielding does not name a type "bar" error in file1.h. 
I thought by including file2.h, bar* would be defined just like foo*
and vice versa.

Comment: Please confirm the compiler settings you're using. Are you compiling this as C or C++? And if so, what version?

Comment: g++ -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

header files should have [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), to protect against
circular include.

circular **dependencies** can be broken using forward declarations,
like you wrote:

```
struct bar;
```

this is because an `#include` directive is just an instruction to the preprocessor to substitute text

this means that the second time in the circular include the preprocessor tries to include a file, the include guard will stop it, and thus the first time the compiler sees `file1.h`, it has not yet seen `file2.h`

Comment: why doesn't it work If I try to use forward declaration in file2.h by adding struct foo; before declaring struct bar. and put foo* foopointer; inside bar? It works however with just struct foo* foopointer; inside bar.

Comment: In the file you are breaking circular dependency using `struct xxx;` you should not include the other file. The easiest way to figure out what's happening here is to compile with -E and read the result of preprocessing

Comment: I shouldn't include the header file in the header files, like include file1 in file2? So do I include them in the cpp files instead?

Comment: In at least one of the header-files you need to break the circular dependency using a forward declaration. In **that** file you should only have the forward declaration, not the include of the other file.

Comment: Thanks, man, I would not figure out about circular dependencies without you. Stackoverflow community should have more people like you. Why do people instant vote down on my post? Is it a very bad post?

Comment: My professor has a discreet way of teaching people programming. He tells people to do programs in certain ways, but he doesn't tell us the troubles that we would face. I do learn a lot from him but he is a pain in the ass.

Comment: Thanks! No, it's not a bad post. And down-voting without leaving a comment on how the post can be improved is frowned upon.